# Angular2 - Property does not exist on type 'Object[]' in http.get

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2. I have searched everywhere for the solution for this problem but I cannot find the answer I need.

Please help me solve this error.
Below is my code:

[image]

mygetApiURL method:

[image]
and below are the error messages:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getApiURL()` returns `Observable<Object[]>`, then you trying to get properties of objects array. You need to set proper return value, for example `getApiURL():Observable<any>`: